# Bad file name or number when trying to read string from .txt

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get this error when I try to open a text file for input. The code looks all right to me...

```
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
 filePath = "C:\Users\" & enviro & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\path.txt"
 Open filePath For Input As #1
 Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strPath
 Loop
 Close #1
```

I intend the text file to have only one line, which is the path towards a workbook.

Comment: Just use `filePath = enviro & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\path.txt"` because `Environ("USERPROFILE")` will be something like `C:\Users\NAlexP`

Comment: Yes, this worked. Would you like to answer the question so I can set it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Environ("USERPROFILE")` will return e.g.:

```
C:\Users\NAlexP
```

So you need to amend the `filePath` assignment to just:

```
filePath = enviro & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\path.txt"
```